# What would be an example for Frame.mapCols?

Tags: f#, deedle

I am trying to create examples for all the methods in Deedle, with mixed success. I was able to provide an example for `Frame.filterColValues` but not for `Frame.mapCols`. Stealing from one of Tomas Petricek's numerous writeups, I defined a DataFrame as follows:

```
open Deedle

let dates  = 
  [ DateTime(2013,1,1); 
    DateTime(2013,1,4); 
    DateTime(2013,1,8) ]

let values = [ 10.0; 20.0; 30.0 ]

let first = Series(dates, values)

/// Generate date range from 'first' with 'count' days
let dateRange (first:System.DateTime) count =
    seq {for i in 0..(count - 1) -> first.AddDays(float i)}

/// Generate 'count' number of random doubles
let rand count =
    let rnd = System.Random()
    seq {for i in 0..(count - 1) -> rnd.NextDouble()}

// A series with values for 10 days 
let second = Series(dateRange (DateTime(2013,1,1)) 10, rand 10)

// df1 has two columns
let df1 = Frame(["first"; "second"], [first; second])
```

Next I was able to provide an example for `Frame.filterColValues`:

```
let df2 = Frame.filterColValues (fun s -> (s.GetAtAs<double>(0) > 5.0)) df1
// df2 has only one column
Frame.toArray2D(df2)
```

But I could not (and I tried hard) create an example for `Frame.map cols`. The best I could come up with was:

```
let df3 = Frame.mapCols (fun k x -> x.GetAtAs<double>(0)) df1
error FS0001: The type 'double' is not compatible with the type 'ISeries<'a>'
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone post an example? Or, even better, point to a place where there are examples for the Deedle methods?

Comment: You can just read description of functions ;)

Comment: so, example: 
`let df2 = 
    df1 
    |> Frame.mapCols(fun _ -> Series.fillMissingInside Direction.Backward)`

Comment: just curious - What you want to get with this function?

Comment: @FoggyFinder - It was the function description that got me confused. It says "Builds a new data frame whose columns are the results of applying the specified function on the columns of the input data frame." This suggests the function has only one argument. The next sentence "Thefunction is called with the column key and object series that represents the column data." suggests it has two arguments. Your own example has `_` as its only argument and I confess I do not understand why it works (I checked it does). The examples provided by Tomas Petricek have two arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Frame.mapCols` function lets you transform a column series into another column series.

The most basic example is just to return the column series unchanged:

```
df1 
|> Frame.mapCols (fun k col -> col)
```

As Foggy Finder mentioned in a comment, you can fill all missing values in a column using this - the body of the lambda has to return a series:

```
df1 
|> Frame.mapCols (fun k v -> Series.fillMissingWith 0.0 v)
```

If you wanted, you could return a series with just a single element (this turns your frame into a frame with one row - containing data from the first row - and original number of columns):

```
df1 
|> Frame.mapCols (fun k col -> series [ 0 => col.GetAtAs<float>(0) ])
```

In your code snippet, it looks like you wanted just a series (with a single value for each column), which can be done by getting the columns and then using `Series.map`:

```
df1.Columns
|> Series.map (fun k col -> col.GetAtAs<float>(0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I got confused by the function description (see my comment above) but also by the function signature that mentions ObjectSeries and #ISeries, two concepts I was not familiar with.